# Web pages doesn't recognize autofill text

Tags: delphi-xe

I'm trying to fill input fields on a web page, but when I press the "Log In" button I got a message "Please fill username/password".

After I write down, on the input box, one character and delete it, it's possible to auto click the "log in" button.
I'm using this code:

```
var ie: Variant;
    ovElements: OleVariant;

ie := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
ie.Visible := true;
ie.Navigate('https://ic2.globalblue.com/pilot/issuing');
ovElements := ie.Document.forms.item(0).elements;
ovElements.item(0).value := 'USERNAME';
ovElements.item(1).value := 'PASSWORD';
// I have to press one key on each input field to the next command to work.
ovElements.item(2).Click;
```

How can I auto fill this kind of input fields?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using IE for this, instead of an HTTP client library/component, like the one in Indy, ICS, Synapse, WinInet, etc?

Comment: The TWebBrowser is giving script errors and doesn't load the page after the login

Comment: that still doesn't explain why you are using visual controls for non-visual work. This should be handled using HTTP libraries, not browser wrappers.

Comment: Because I need to show the page to the user on a webbrowser